# Split mf4 files

Tags: python, asammdf

I have a memory problem when trying to convert mf4 files larger than 7mb (example 100mb). I would like to split my files larger than 7MB into several 7MB files. Is this possible?

Here is the error I have with the memory for large files
`Unable to allocate 123. MiB for an array with shape (3570125,) and data type |S36`

Comment: what are the specs of the PC ?

Comment: locally I work with a MacBook Pro (16", 2019), 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7 6 cores, 6 GB 2667 MHz DDR4 and in the cloud on a vm windows server Intel Haswell 150gb ram

Comment: the MF4 file might use compression internally so you can get into memory errors with only 6Gb of RAM

Comment: Can you also share your pytho code used to process the file?